# Customize Origin Protocol Policy for S3-website origins (HTTP-only)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Previously I've been able to configure the "Origin Protocol Policy" for my S3 website endpoints so that they are HTTP-only. This is [still advised here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy).

Now [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html) states that the default value for "Origin Protocol Policy" is "Match Viewer" and that it cannot be changed.

Is this a recent change? I still have several origins with "Origin Protocol Policy" set to "HTTP only" but can't find any way to change it for more recently created distributions/origins.

How do I now serve my Cloudfront S3-website-backed distributions via HTTPS?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

X-Post from [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=242996&tstart=0) because not much activity there :(

Comment: I've walked through creating and modifying a distribution and the console seems to do the right thing -- if you type the bucket's website endpoint into the box and not from the dropdown, the value is automatically set to HTTP-Only on the origin protocol policy (the only valid option).  Viewer protocol policy is HTTP and HTTPS.  So, it is no longer configurable, it "just works." The docs are referring to "S3" (REST), not "S3 website."  Can you describe exactly the current state of one of your new distributions and what you want to change, so that I can understand exactly what isn't working?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're right! Wow. This is so backwards :D Typing (or copy-pasting) the S3 website URL indeed did the trick where as choosing the endpoint from the dropdown didn't work as desired. Wanna add as answer so I can mark as answered?

Comment: I guess it's my fault because I didn't properly provide the website endpoint but rather just the bucket. Didn't notice that because of long bucket names... >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was my fault. I provided the regular S3 endpoint as Origin URL without noticing (the origin name does not change so double check the actual URL if you're experiencing a similar problem).

Once I provided the website endpoint as Origin URL the Origin Protocol Policy was set to "HTTP only" **automatically**. After that everything worked as expected.